# Getting values out of array gives strange values

Tags: c++, arduino

After an hour of trying I ended up with this:

```
  ...
  for(int j = 0; j < woorden[i] -> getSize(); j++){
                int *test = woorden[i]->leds;
                lightupLed(*test);
                test++;
    }
  ...
```

The thing it should do is get all the integers out of the 'leds' array and call the lightupLed function. However, the values I get are for example -21515 or 11518. While the values should be between 0 - 117.
The 'woorden' array contains custom objects of the type 'woord' (see below).
If you need more information, just ask. 
Thanks in advance!

**Woord.h**

```
class Woord {
 public:
   int leds[13];
   int size = 0;
   String naam = "";

   Woord();
   Woord(int l[], int arraysize, String nm);
   int getSize();
   String getNaam();
};
```

**Woord.cpp**

```
Woord::Woord(){}
Woord::Woord(int l[], int arraysize, String nm) {
    //std::array<int,4> B
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
        leds[i] = l[i];
    }
    naam = nm;
    size = arraysize;
}
int Woord::getSize(){
    return size;
}
String Woord::getNaam(){
    return naam;
}
```

Comment: Your default constructor doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `test++;` appears to be pointless as the last statement in a block (loop body) where it immediately thereafter falls out of scope.

Comment: Yeah, I should delete that...

Comment: Reading [this](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) should help. You should run your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious mistake is that you define `test` each iteration. Maybe, `lightupLed(woorden[i]->leds[j]);` is what you want to do.

Comment: I did this at the beginning, but the values kept being weird.